How to control a 12V DC siren with Raspberry Pi GPIO?
I'm currently working on a project where I need to control a 12V DC siren using my Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins. I want to be able to play and pause the siren programmatically through my Raspberry Pi.
I've done some research, but I'm not entirely sure about the correct approach and the components needed for this setup. Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly connect and control the 12V DC Siren with Raspberry Pi GPIO? Additionally, I'd appreciate any tips on the programming side to implement the play/pause functionality.
Any help, suggestions, or sample code?
Note: I am a newbie, I directly connected siren with jumper wires but GPIO supports 3.3V and siren is 12V and it didn't work obviously.

The Pi has not enough Power (Voltage AND Current) to drive this Siren. You have to bypass the Power from an external 12 V DC Power Supply. Then, on the second hand, you have to Connect the Pi with the Siren with a galvanic isolation. You can reach this with a relais:
https://amzn.in/d/5OXuk0p
At first, try to activate the relais, and then you can reach for the next Target. Take care for your ears, this Sirens can be realy loud, if they`re spotted to your face.

the relay would also require a driver circuit, same as the siren

The Relay which I linked, has a built in Driver for the optocouppler. With this Board you have a Led which indicates you, if your GPIO is High or Low.
I realy think it is important for a beginner to start with a galvanic isolation.

then it is not a relay, it is a relay module
